# Can I use core data with a sprite kit game?

Tags: ios, core-data, sprite-kit

I'm very new to core data. I'd like to use it with a sprite kit game, but I don't see the usual option to check mark it like I did with a generic xcode project. Is it still possible to use it? If so what are the steps that I have to do to configure it?

Comment: Create a new non Sprite Kit app project with Core Data and see what gets created. Copy the Core Data related files to your Sprite Kit project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can certainly use core data with sprite kit game.  The default sprite kit game template in Xcode does not provide an option for including core data in the starter project but you can always include core data in a sprite kit game by copying the boiler plate core data code in the AppDelegate file.  There is no restriction on using core data in a sprite kit game.